# Interactive search of tmux sessions

Tags: linux, command-line, tmux, bsd, command-line-tool

When switching between tmux sessions with the interactive session menu (`<prefix>-s`), you can jump to a specific session by typing the session's numeric or alphabetical index, e.g.

`(0) + first_session: 1 windows
 (1) + second_session: 2 windows
 (2) + third_session: 1 windows
 (3) + secret_session: 1 windows`

Pressing `1` will open up the `second_session` session.

I often have >20 tmux sessions open and I'd like to have a way to search without looking at the whole list. Is there a way to change the behaviour to have an interactive search? That is, I would like to type `sec` and have the list narrow to

`(1) + second_session: 2 windows
 (3) + secret_session: 1 windows`

I've googled quite a bit and found nothing; is this behaviour possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it is, but as far as i know you'll need an extra tool for the searching itself.
I'm using [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) for the (fuzzy) searching. Once fzf is installed you can use the following config to set up the session switching with search:

```
bind C-j split-window -v "tmux list-sessions | sed -E 's/:.*$//' | grep -v \"^$(tmux display-message -p '#S')\$\" | fzf --reverse | xargs tmux switch-client -t"
```

I didn't figure this out myself but took this from Chris Toomey's [public tmux conf](https://github.com/christoomey/dotfiles/blob/f3f9da69586503823de9ff075fbf627ec2bb6fb5/tmux/tmux.conf#L107).

Comment: This is freaking amazing!

Comment: please pardon my tmux nubeness.. but I'm not sure what to type to reach that point? this is what i have in my tmux.conf file:

`set-option -g prefix C-a
..
the above shortuct (ie bind C-j split-window..`
so what do i type from a terminal to see this quick search thing?

Comment: @abbood I had the same problem, well you have to press your prefix key + ctrl j for it to open the search pane. For me prefix + c opens a new tmux window, so I changed the above to `bind j` and now I just press my prefix key + j and the search begins, sweet!

Answer (score 0):

@bartj3: Thanks. This is super cool!

Here is a slightly enhanced version (w/o sed and grep) for both switching sessions and windows:

```
bind j split-window -v "tmux list-sessions -F '#S' | fzf --reverse | xargs tmux switch-client -t"
bind k split-window -v "tmux list-window -F '#W' | fzf --reverse | xargs tmux select-window -t"
```

PROBLEM:

If you use the above while synchronize-panes is on, your search key-strokes will also type in the other panes.

QUESTION:

Does anyone have an idea on how to limit the key-strokes to the search-pane?

Comment: While this answer actually does appear to answer the question.  The fact you submitted your own question, within the answer body, makes it impossible to answers your question.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser!  Your answer includes another question.  Your question will get the appropriate attention if you post it as a new question.  Please review site guidelines on [ask] and [answer].  Also, you will find that you will have a better experience if you take moment to take the Stack Overflow [tour].  If you follow the norms of the Stack Overflow community and approach it with an attitude of helping others too, it will serve you well.

Comment: Ok. Posted as a new question in https://superuser.com/questions/1397211. Thanks.